# How to pass value from react native state to webview

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, android-webview, react-native-navigation

I am using a react-native webview package in my react native project.

I do want to pass the params from react native to the url to show inside the webview

My react native code.

Here,i have the access to retrieve the user email from the login page. I want to pass the email id to the url or to the page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class NewScreen extends Component {
  //const email = this.props.route.params.email;
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isShow:true,
      email:''
    }
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    const email = this.props.route.params.email;
    this.windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    this.windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;  
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    //console.log('Mounted')
    //console.log('state',this.props.email)
    console.log('mail',this.props.route.params.email)
    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://xxx/add-new-submit-form.php?email=abcd@gmail.com'
        }}
        
      />
    );
  }
}

export default NewScreen;
```

My expected result.

**const email_id = this.props.route.params.email** -> It holds the email id of the user.

Now I need to pass the value of email_id to the php url

php url in the webview **uri = https://xxx/add-new-submit-form.php?email=abcd@gmail.com'**

I want to pass the value of the user email id in the uri.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it. Simply this should work:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  //...rest of the code
  const email_id = this.props.route.params.email;
  setState({ url: `https://xxx/add-new-submit-form.php?email=${email_id}` />
}

//On Render
<WebView source={{ uri: this.state.url }} />
```